# IRB (apparently) not inspecting hashes correctly

Tags: ruby, hash, irb

I'm seeing some odd behavior in IRB 1.8.7 with printing hashes. If I initialize my hash with a `Hash.new`, it appears that my hash is "evaluating" to an empty hash:

```
irb(main):024:0> h = Hash.new([])
=> {}
irb(main):025:0> h["test"]
=> []                                                        
irb(main):026:0> h["test"] << "blah"                    
=> ["blah"]                                         
irb(main):027:0> h                              
=> {}                                                  
irb(main):028:0> puts h.inspect                       
{}                                                               
=> nil                 
irb(main):031:0> require 'pp'     
=> true                           
irb(main):032:0> pp h             
{}                                
=> nil                            
irb(main):033:0> h["test"]
=> ["blah"]
```

As you can see, the data *is* actually present in the hash, but trying to print or display it seems to fail. Initialization with a hash literal seems to fix this problem:

```
irb(main):050:0> hash = { 'test' => ['testval'] }
=> {"test"=>["testval"]}
irb(main):051:0> hash
=> {"test"=>["testval"]}
irb(main):053:0> hash['othertest'] = ['secondval']
=> ["secondval"]
irb(main):054:0> hash
=> {"othertest"=>["secondval"], "test"=>["testval"]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that invoking `h["test"]` doesn't actually insert a new key into the hash - it just returns the default value, which is the array that you passed to `Hash.new`.

```
1.8.7 :010 > a = []
 => []
1.8.7 :011 > a.object_id
 => 70338238506580
1.8.7 :012 > h = Hash.new(a)
 => {}
1.8.7 :013 > h["test"].object_id
 => 70338238506580
1.8.7 :014 > h["test"] << "blah"
 => ["blah"]
1.8.7 :015 > h.keys
 => []
1.8.7 :016 > h["bogus"]
 => ["blah"]
1.8.7 :017 > h["bogus"].object_id
 => 70338238506580
1.8.7 :019 > a
 => ["blah"]
```

The hash itself is still empty - you haven't assigned anything to it. The data isn't present in the hash - it's present in the array that is returned for missing keys in the hash.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to create a hash of arrays. To do so, I recommend you initialize like so:

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
```

Your version isn't working correctly for me, either. The reason why is a little complicated to understand. [From the docs:](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html#method-c-new)

> If *obj* is specified, this **single object** will be used for all *default values*.

I've added the bolding. The rest of the emphasis is as-is.

You're specifying that `obj` is `[]`, and it's only a default value. It doesn't actually **set** the contents of the hash to that default value. So when you do `h["blah"] << "test"`, you're really just asking it to return a copy of the default value and then adding `"test"` to that copy. It never goes into the hash at all. (I need to give Chris Heald credit for explaining this below.)

If instead you give it a block, it calls that block EVERY TIME you do a lookup on a non-existent entry of the hash. So you're not just creating one Array anymore. You're creating one for each entry of the hash.